How to Rearrange the column order of a csv file
Am trying to rearrange the column order of below sample data ,
USI,CFG LEI,Counterparty LEI,UPI,Product Class,Execution venue,MTM,Currency 1,Currency 2,Notional amount 1,Notional amount 2,Exchange rate,Delivery type,Settlement or expiration date,Execution Venue LEI,Indication of collateralization,Trade ID,CounterParty full Name,Start Date,Deal Code,Settlement Currency,Valuation Fixing Date,Trade Date and timestamp,CIS Code (Internal),Trade Description,UTI,Is CFG Reporting Party?,Contract type,UTI Leg 2 ,Counterparty purchasing protection ,Counterparty selling protection ,Reference Entity ,Maturity Date ,Price ,Cap Strike ,Floor Strike ,Notional Amount ,Notional Currency ,Upfront Payment Amount ,Upfront Payment Currency ,Payment frequency of the reporting counterparty. ,Payment frequency of the non-reporting counterparty ,Day count convention ,Notional amount (leg 1) ,Notional currency (leg 1) ,Notional amount (leg 2) ,Notional currency (leg 2) ,Pay Leg Type (CFG) ,Receive Leg Type (CFG) ,Direction ,Option type ,Fixed rate ,Fixed rate 2 ,Fixed rate day count fraction ,Floating rate payment frequency ,Floating rate reset frequency ,Floating rate index name/rate period ,Floating rate Index 2 ,Buyer ,Seller ,Quantity unit ,Quantity frequency ,Total quantity ,Total Remaining Quantity ,Notional ,Settlement method ,Price unit ,Price currency ,Buyer pay index ,Buyer pay averaging method ,Seller pay index ,Seller pay averaging method ,Grade ,Option style ,Option premium ,Hours from through ,Hours from through time zone ,Days of week ,Load type

,DRMSV1Q0EKMEXLAU1P80,549300UGRJZFKLBDNB67,,FXF,OffFacility,-6573.66,EUR,USD,817785,923933.49,1.1298,Physical,4/13/2028,,Uncollateralized,2.02304E+12,AG NET LEASE RLTY FND IV Q LP,4/12/2023,B,,,12-Apr-23,AA077C7,FX FORWARD TRANSACTION,DRMSV1Q0EKMEXLAU1P80WSSFX202304120000436044681000001,Y,FX FORWARD TRANSACTION,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,DRMSV1Q0EKMEXLAU1P80,549300UGRJZFKLBDNB67,,FXF,OffFacility,-6573.66,EUR,USD,817785,923933.49,1.1298,Physical,4/13/2028,,Uncollateralized,2.02304E+12,AG NET LEASE RLTY FND IV Q LP,4/12/2023,B,,,12-Apr-23,AA077C7,FX FORWARD TRANSACTION,DRMSV1Q0EKMEXLAU1P80WSSFX202304120000436044681000001,Y,FX FORWARD TRANSACTION,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

To achieve that am trying below shell script,
   #!/bin/bash
 
 #Reordering the  columns
    
     
    
    temp_file=$(mktemp)
    
     
    
    mlr --csv reorder -f "\"Trade ID\",\"Trade Date and timestamp\",\"CounterParty full Name\",\"CIS Code (Internal)\",\"Trade Description\",\"USI\",\"UTI\",\"UTI Leg 2\",\"CFG LEI\",\"Counterparty LEI\",\"Is CFG Reporting Party?\",\"UPI\",\"Contract type\",\"Execution venue\",\"Execution Venue LEI\",\"Counterparty purchasing protection\",\"Counterparty selling protection\",\"Reference Entity\",\"Start Date\",\"Maturity Date\",\"Price\",\"Cap Strike\",\"Floor Strike\",\"Notional Amount\",\"Notional Currency\",\"Upfront Payment Amount\",\"Upfront Payment Currency\",\"Payment frequency of the reporting counterparty.\",\"Payment frequency of the non-reporting counterparty\",\"Currency 1\",\"Currency 2\",\"Notional amount 1\",\"Notional amount 2\",\"Exchange rate\",\"Delivery type\",\"Settlement or expiration date\",\"Day count convention\",\"Notional amount (leg 1)\",\"Notional currency (leg 1)\",\"Notional amount (leg 2)\",\"Notional currency (leg 2)\",\"Pay Leg Type (CFG)\",\"Receive Leg Type (CFG)\",\"Direction\",\"Option type\",\"Fixed rate\",\"Fixed rate 2\",\"Fixed rate day count fraction\",\"Floating rate payment frequency\",\"Floating rate reset frequency\",\"Floating rate index name/rate period\",\"Floating rate Index 2\",\"Buyer\",\"Seller\",\"Quantity unit\",\"Quantity frequency\",\"Total quantity\",\"Total Remaining Quantity\",\"Notional\",\"Settlement method\",\"Price unit\",\"Price currency\",\"Buyer pay index\",\"Buyer pay averaging method\",\"Seller pay index\",\"Seller pay averaging method\",\"Grade\",\"Option style\",\"Option premium\",\"Hours from through\",\"Hours from through time zone\",\"Days of week\",\"Load type\",\"Indication of collateralization\",\"MTM\",\"Product Class\",\"Deal Code\",\"Settlement Currency\",\"Valuation Fixing Date\"" Wallstreet_Source_File.csv > "$temp_file"
    
     
    
    mv "$temp_file" Wallstreet_Source_File.csv

While executing the mentioned shell script getting below error
mlr CSV header/data length mismatch 79 != 28 at filename Wallstreet_Source_File.csv row2

I am trying to reorder the columns based upon the order mentioned in the script(mlr), Anything is missing or any other approach to achieve it.

consider reviewing minimal, reproducible example and then come back and update the question; in particular, provide a sample with 5-6 columns (instead of the current 80), the expected output, and some description of how you determine the new column order (eg, are you reading the column list from a file? are you matching the column list from a second file, or will you always be manually editing the column list?)

i am reading the column list within the same file,I need to reorder it within the the single csv file which has 79 columns, i will edit my question with few columns , if i got solution i will try to apply it for the actual number of columns

yes, I understand the file has column headings; my question was: how are you determining the new order of the columns? is this something you'll always do manually or do you obtain the new column ordering from a different file?

have you tried running a web search on awk reorder columns?

I see you tagged your question with [tag:cd] - what does cd have to do with it?

If you are allowed to install tool I suggest trying csvcut from csvkit, which can be used to reorder columns as follows, let file.csv content be
Able,Baker,Charlie
1,2,3
4,5,6

then
csvcut --columns "Able,Charlie,Baker" file.csv

gives ouput
Able,Charlie,Baker
1,3,2
4,6,5

